# Не получается загрузить базу в SQLite из файла db.sqlite

Tags: linux, sqlite, sqlite3

Установил SQLite в Linux.
Командой

```
sqlite3 -column -header db.sqlite
```

создал базу.

Далее мне дали базу c данными в виде файла db.sqlite.
Положил ее сначала в /home. В документации написано, что можно по-горячему заменить старый файл этим новым. Но поискал аналогичный файл в Linux-его не нашел. Нашел только файл db.3.gz.
Куда положить файл db.sqlite, чтобы созданная база заменилась им? Впервые с SQLite пришлось возиться.
Захожу в SQLite и пытаюсь проверить схему или сделать запрос к данным - ноль информации-ничего не выдает.

Comment: Файла с данными db.sqlite изначально не было. Я так понимаю, он должен был сначала создаться чистый по команде. А потом его можно было бы заменить вторым файлом и войти в SqLile, чтобы работать с данными.

Comment: Для работы с БД ничего предварительно создавать не надо. Передаёте при старте утилите имя файла и вперёд - работайте с БД: `sqlite3 db.sqlite` https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у программы *sqlite* [база данных — это один файл](https://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html). такой файл содержит базу данных, и этим файлом база данных и исчерпывается (если не считать временно создаваемых журнальных файлов для управления транзакциями).

командой

```
$ sqlite3 имя.файла
```

вы создали в текущем каталоге файл с именем `имя.файла`, содержащий базу данных. (имя файла может быть абсолютно произвольным, и если вы использовали в имени суффикс `.sqlite`, то это было всего лишь для вашего удобства).

если вам надо заменить этот файл другим (с точки зрения программы *sqlite* — заменить одну базу данных другой), просто замените его любым удобным для вас способом. естественно, процесс *sqlite*, использующий старый файл, лучше перед этим завершить.

когда вы вновь запустите программу *sqlite*, в том же каталоге, где вы создали, а потом заменили файл, содержащий базу данных, и передав ей то же самое имя файла в качестве аргумента, программа «увидит» уже новое содержимое файла (другими словами — новое содержимое базы данных).