# Где лучше всего размещать код создания таблицы базы данных?

Tags: python, sqlite

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня есть программа, которая состоит из модуля main, класса persona и класса database. В database там будет происходить добавление, изменение и удаление в базе, а где лучше всего разместить создание этой базы, чтобы при первом запуске программы создала базу и больше этот код не выполнялся, как это можно реализовать или может я ни так это вообще понимаю
Я использую sqlite3
Где разместить вот этот код:

```
conn = sql.connect('data_per.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            id INTEGER,
            name TEXT,
            gender TEXT,
            weight REAL,
            height INT,
            age INT,
            coefficient REAL
            );
        """)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: А сам файл с базой `data_per.db` уже откуда-то будет?

Comment: Вообще я хочу чтобы он создавался во время первого запуска программы, в котором создается таблица, и с ней я уже потом буду проводить действия

Comment: Могу ли я просто в отдельном модуле создать этот файл с базой и потом его  использовать в своем проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда уже сделайте метод в database, чтобы весь код по БД был в одном месте. А при запуске программы сделайте проверку на наличие БД, если ее нет, то вызывается метод создания.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, а как можно реализовать проверку на наличие БД?

Comment: @Tesla, проверяйте [наличие файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1249846/178576)

Comment: Простите, прочитал, но ничего не понял, как можно реализовать проверку на наличие БД в проекте((

Comment: Я все понял, разобрался сам, спасибо